# What is the fastest delete method for many directory on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, remove

I have to remove many directory.
but

```
rm -r /data
```

is so slow ( about some days)
/data has

/data/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h ....

many dirs

Does anyone know?

Comment: Is `\data` perhaps a separate file system?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/296032/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-remove-thousands-of-files-on-a-btrfs-filesystem

Answer (score 3):

Removing huge amount of files and directories is a long operation, no matter what file system you have in use. Depending on your I/O subsystem and file system it might help performing the removal in parallel; just put one rm process removing directories starting with `a-f`, another one with `g-n`, and third one with `o-z`. Or something like that.

Or if it's OK for you to just have file removal going on background, you can always

```
mv data data_to_be_removed
mkdir data
rm -rf data_to_be_removed
```

Comment: Just what I was in the process of suggesting, Janne - I completely agree with you.  Computers are there to do hard work that takes time, so we don't have to.  `mv` the file system to one side, then `rm -rf` can be happily chewing through it freeing up disc while you get on with putting your new content in place.